# How can I get the value of a complex javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables

[image]

I outputted an array, but it returns a complex array or object. Please see the image. I'm trying to retrieve and store the values 57,62 and 64 but I don't know how to do it. I use console.log. Please help...

Comment: Can you post codes how you `output` that?

Comment: Those values are in: `arr[34][0]`, `arr[34][1]`, and `arr[34][2]`

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you have 2D array that is returning to your javascript. 
Suppose you have variable name is `output` then simply use like

```
output[index of main array][index of sub array]
```

If you need to get 57 value then simply `output[34][0]`.
To get all the values use loop to get and do whatever you want.